# Azure AD MFA is not deterministic

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

I am using Azure services and Azure AD Free (my personal account).
I have setup a tenant and I am Global Admin. I have enabled **Security Default** in the tenant. Hence, I assume MFA is enabled for all the tenant's users.
When I signin to Azure Portal with Global Admin sometime I get **not** prompted for MFA; maybe is this because the browser send a cookie? Or maybe because MFA is not always triggered?
Also, if I open an incognito window I get prompted for a code, received via email. My question here is why email? As per MFA AAD [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-authentication-methods) the email method is **NOT** an MFA channel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Please check if below are the reasons behind not getting the prompt for second verification even MFA is enabled:***

1. Please check if you are a member of any ***exception group***. To avoid lockout situation, Microsoft mostly suggest excluding global admin account while enabling MFA. If you done like that, remove your account from exception group.
2. There is also a possibility where you selected checkbox saying “***Stay signed in***” while logging into your account. Then it will treat your device as ***remembered device*** and suspends enabling MFA. Also please check below screenshot whether you have enabled this option (**Remember MFA on trusted device**). If you enabled that, you won’t get prompts until the duration of days you have given expires.

[image: 1]

To remove all those sessions, enable “**Revoke MFA sessions**” which clears all remembered sessions history and asks for second verification.

[image: 2]

As you already mentioned, MFA code won’t be sent via email.

From this [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-authentication-methods#how-each-authentication-method-works),

> Email address is only used for **Self-Service Password Reset (SSPR)** not
> for authentication.

There is also a possibility where your password is **expired** and it’s sending you a code to your email to reset it as you have given it as **recovery option**.

**NOTE:**

As you are enabling **[Security Defaults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults#protecting-all-users)**, please note that you won't be getting ***MFA*** prompts every time. **Azure AD** decides when a user will be prompted for ***MFA***, based on factors such as **location, device, role and task.**

For suppose, if you are accessing from different location and seemed suspicious means, definitely you will get prompt otherwise you won't. If you need ***MFA*** prompts in particular, make use of **Conditional access policies** that need **Azure AD Premium** licenses.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I've revoked the session but I get same behavior: code via email. For the rest, I can't manage MFA settings since I have AAD free hence I can only enable "Manage Security" setting to enable MFA. I think that maybe the Portal is just remember me as "good user"..

Comment: Hi @toto', please check the edited answer where I added a **Note** that may be reason behind not getting prompts.